# Append values to keys in python dictionary

Tags: python

I am getting an error

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'

for the following python code:

getStats pulls system info and places it in several keys of dictionary, each with one value, writes dictionary to json file, and script stops.
script wakes up hourly, reads json file, takes new getStats sample and should append those new values to appropriate keys, creating lists.

Here's the essence of the script:

```
newDict = getStats()
.
.
. 
oldDict['offset'].append(newDict['offset'])
(Attribute error occurs here)
```

I have a workaround that iterates through the keys' value list, creates new list, appends new value to new list, and writes to appropriate key in oldDict.
Seems klunky....was wondering if there is something missing here.

Here is my json file on first iteration of script:

{"maxError": "275848", "pollingInterval": "512", "timeCorrect": "57", "driftTime": "21.056", "frequency": "21.099", "offset": "288.840"}

Thanks for help!

Comment: if `oldDict['offset']` is a string you cannot append something to it. This leads to the `AttributeError`

Answer (score 3):

The value of the dict['offset'] is a string. You should make it a list if you want to append the new offset. Where you initialize you oldDict, try this:

```
dict['offset'] = []
dict['offset'].append(newDict['offset'])
```

Answer (score 0):

**oldDict['offset']** must hold a type that has no attribute append.

Most likely a string evident from the shared json:

```
{"maxError": "275848", "pollingInterval": "512", "timeCorrect": "57", "driftTime": "21.056", "frequency": "21.099", "offset": "288.840"}
```

Reproduction of the issue:

```
>>> oldDict = {"offset": "1"}
>>> newDict = {"offset": "2"}
>>> oldDict["offset"].append(newDict["offset"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

You need to represent it as a list to use append:

```
>>> oldDict['offset'] = []
>>> oldDict['offset'].append(newDict['offset'])
```

Be careful with what you pass to **append()**. If you give it another list which is what newDict["offset"] will have if you go the list way in **getStats()**, it will add the list at the end of the list in oldDict['offset']

```
>>> oldDict = {"offset": ["1"]}
>>> oldDict["offset"]
['1']
>>> newDict = {"offset": ["2"]}
>>> newDict["offset"]
['2']
>>> oldDict["offset"].append(newDict["offset"]) 
>>> oldDict["offset"]
['1', ['2']]
```

You instead need to pass the value(s) if you are looking to only add the value(s) of newDict["offset"] into in oldDict["offset"] in which case you may need list comprehension:

```
>>> oldDict = {"offset": ["1"]}
>>> oldDict["offset"]
['1']
>>> newDict = {"offset": ["2"]}
>>> newDict["offset"]
['2']
>>> [oldDict["offset"].append(item) for item in newDict["offset"]]
[None]
>>> oldDict["offset"]
['1', '2']
```

or simply use **+** on the lists:

```
>>> oldDict = {"offset": ["1"]}
>>> newDict = {"offset": ["2"]}
>>> oldDict["offset"] + newDict["offset"]
['1', '2']
```

Comment: Agree with logic of initialization for list oldDict['offset'] = [] ... although this overwrites data already stored in value...for anyone reading this, my workaround is this: 

oldDict['offset'] = setList(oldDict, 'offset', newDict['offset'])   

and  

def setList(listGoesHere, keyName, newValue):
    newList = []
    for key in listGoesHere:
        if keyName in key:
            newList.append(listGoesHere[key])
    newList.append(newValue)
    return newList

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to copy every key and value from one dictionary to a new one, I would use this:

```
oldDict = {} 
oldDict['offset'] = 'some_value'

newDict = {}

for key, value in oldDict.items():
   newDict[key] = value
```

If you wanted to copy only a specific set of keys with their value, you could use something like this:

```
oldDict = {}
oldDict['offset'] = 'some_value'
oldDict['other'] = 'other_value'

newDict = {}

for key, value in oldDict.items():
    if key == 'offset':
        newDict[key] = value
```

This would only add the key and value if it was `'offset'`

Comment: One factor that may affect this i didn't go into was the script runs once every hour and dump it's data into a json file...every time it runs, it json.loads the file, takes new samples, and adds those samples to the key values -- in this case, value is a list. Maybe json wasn't designed for all this. In the past, simple key value pairs have worked fine. Here, I'm branching out to something new with lists....

Comment: I'm sorry I was out of lane answering this, I glanced and thought was a simple problem, I'm new, not even aware of json or files etc, just was trying to be helpful, excuse my ignorance

Comment: th open('/tmp/ntpOutput.json') as fr:
            oldJsonFileDict = json.load(fr)
        fr.close()

        newestJsonDict['offset'] = []
        newestJsonDict['offset'].append(oldJsonFileDict['offset'])
        newestJsonDict['offset'].append(varOne)

        with open('/tmp/ntpOutput.json', 'w') as fw:
            fw.write(json.dumps(newestJsonDict))
        fw.close()

produces this, bunches of ['s and ]'s -- do you know why that would be:

{"offset": [[["32.851", "32.835"], "32.819"], "32.803"]}

Comment: hmm when you call newestJsonDict['offset'] =[] are you setting the key to be a library, and then its calling a library, could you try setting newesJsonDict['offset'] = [''] , tell me what happens

Comment: if not i would try accessing the keys through a `for key,value in xxx.items()` and copying the pair using the second part of the solution I submitted